# What is wrong with my proof that this is an equivalence relation

Tags: set-theory

I need to prove that the relation $a_1b_1=a_2b_2$ is an equivalence relation for the set $\{(a, b): a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, a,b \ne0\}$

I've done the following:

- Reflexivity: $a_1b_1=a_1b_1$
- Symmetric: $a_1b_1=a_2b_2 \iff a_2b_2=a_1b_1$
- Transitive: $a_1b_1=a_2b_2 \text{ and } a_2b_2=a_3b_3 \Longrightarrow a_1b_1=a_3b_3$

  since you can substitute $a_2b_2$ with $a_1b_1$

I feel like all of the above obviously follow (I hope...)

Now the problem is that this relation according to the question isn't an equivalence relation for the set $\{(a, b): a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

But I feel like my proof still holds for that second set as well? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the question actually say? Copy it verbatim, if you can. It would be odd for a question to imply that a statement can be proved (implied by asking you to provide proof) and at the same time not.

Comment: Are you sure you have the subscripts correct? Would expect this to be about rational numbers as an equivalence class of numerator denominator pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that yes, the relation $R$, defined as $(a_1,b_1)R(a_2,b_2)\iff a_1b_1=a_2b_2$ is indeed an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z^2$, not only on $\{(a,b)|a,b\neq 0\}$. However, I strongly suspect that the relation you were really meant to examine is the relation

$$(a_1,b_1)R(a_2,b_2)\iff a_1b_2=a_2b_1$$ which is not an equivalence relation if you allow $a_1, a_2$ to be zero. For example, $(1,1)R(0,0)$ is true in such a case, and so is $(0,0)R(1,2)$, however $(1,1)R(1,2)$ is not true.

*In fact, $(a,b)R(0,0)$ is always true :)*

---

But more importantly, let me share my two favorite quotes from two of my TAs from back when I was a freshman

> 1. My dear colleague, "obvious" is not a word that is allowed to be in you vocabulary until you are at least a postgrad.
> 2. Well if its obvious, it shouldn't take us more than a minute to prove, right? Surely we can spare a minute.

In other words, as a student, when proving something, do **not** just claim the entire statement is "obvious".

What I would expect from a beginner student when proving that a relation is an equivalence relation is basically this (with empty lines filled out, of course).

> Statement: Relation $R$ on $A$ is an equivalence relation.
>
> Proof:
>
> 1. **$R$ is reflexive**. By definition, $R$ is reflexive if, for every $a\in A$, we have that $aRa$ is true. Let $a\in A$ be an
>    arbitrary element. Then,
>    _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________, and therefore, $aRa$ is true. Since $a$ was arbitrary, this proves $R$
>    is reflexive.
> 2. **$R$ is symmetrical**. By definition, $R$ is symmetrical if, for every $a_1, a_2\in A$, the statement $a_1Ra_2\iff a_2Ra_1$ is true.
>    Let $a_1, a_2\in A$ be arbitrary. Then,
>    ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________...
> 3. **$R$ is transitive**. By definition, $R$ is transitive if, for every $a_1, a_2, a_3\in A$, we know that if $a_1Ra_2$ and $a_2Ra_3$,
>    then $a_1Ra_3$. Let $a_1,a_2,a_3\in A$ be arbitrary elements. Let us
>    also assume that $a_1Ra_2$ and $a_2Ra_3$.
>    Then,_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ which means that $a_1Ra_3$. Because we started with the assumption
>    $a_1Ra_2$ and $a_2Ra_3$, this proves the implication $(a_1Ra_2\land
>    > a_2Ra_3)\implies a_1Ra_3$. Because all three elements were arbitrary,
>    this proves the implication is true for all elements of $A$, which
>    proves $R$ is symmetric.

Now, admittedly, the proofs are rather wordy, and they **could** be shortened, but only if you know what it is that you are shortening. And just saying "oh, all three statements are obvious" is not it. For one thing, in a good proof, even if it skips over some steps, one will **always** know what a given symbol represents, and what quantifier the variable is bound by. For example, in my proof, in step $1$, you can see that $a$ is an arbitrary element of $A$. We know that whatever is written about $A$ must be true for every element of $A$.

In your case, when you say "Oh, it's reflexive because $a_1b_1=a_2b_2$", this is not clear.